# How to stop SSH pipe from dying due to inactivity in Konsole

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux, linux-terminal

I have a super efficient Konsole profile setup just the way I like it with my prefered shortcuts.

Lately I have been spending a lot of time in the terminal connected to a remote server through SSH. I spend a lot of time looking at logs and even doing development on the server using Vim and nano

Some times, after a long period I come back to my session and it is dead, and I have to use SSH to connect again, type my password which is relatively long, navigate to a location and do whatever I need to do. I end up losing a minute or two doing this mostly due to long input delay and the login delay.

I talked to a previous coworker who now works as a sys admin and he suggested that I use tmux. I have used tmux before and I liked it but i really like my current setup. Is there a way to set up an eternal ssh connection on Konsole?

Comment: You can configure ssh client/server to send keepalive packets https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084288/keep-ssh-session-alive

Comment: I don't know anything about Konsole, but could you run Konsole inside of a tmux session?

Comment: @mattb I dont think that is a solution. A solution would be the opposite - running tmux inside of konsole, but then I'd have to use the tmux shortcuts for the most part. I will try Robert's solution later, I am at work right now. I am pretty sure it will work, i will post an update later.